# Unable to resolve path to module './src/somponents/header' (import/no-unresolved) | React Native | ESLint

Tags: react-native, jsx, eslint

I spent a lot of time finding the solution for this question but I couldn't find the perfect answer for this.

**This is header.js file**

 I am getting "*Unable to resolve path to module './src/somponents/header' (import/no-unresolved)*" in this file.

```
//  Import Libraries to make components
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

//  Make a component
const Header = () => {
    return <Text>Albums</Text>;
};

//  Make the component available to the other parts of the app
export default Header;
```

**This is index.android.js file**

 I am getting "*Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body*" in this file near const App = () => (

```
//  Importing the libraries
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/somponents/header';

//  Creating a component
const App = () => (
    <Header />
);

//  Rendering the component
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

I am totally new to React Native. Please help me solve this error.

Thank You

Comment: For the "arrow body" warning you could try to fix it automatically by running 'eslint --fix'. It's probably same as this https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5498#issuecomment-226895990. So you can just remove the parenthesis and return statement where you create the Header.